# I want to select only numeric from dropdown but in list it have same values Alphanumeric and Numeric in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

**Want to automate:**

[image: Dropdown list]

**My Code:**

[image: Code]

```js
cy.get('[role=presentation]') cy.get('[role=row]').find('td')
  .get('[role=gridcell]').eq(9).click().wait(2000) 
cy.get('[role=listbox]').get('[role=option]') 

cy.contains('[role=option]', 'Numeric').click()
```

How can I select only "Numeric" from list, if the list contains other values with that text.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of code into code blocks? Likely useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking about how to do an ***exact*** match to the option "Numeric", so that the option "AlphaNumeric" is excluded from the search.

To do this, change your `cy.contains()` command to use a regular expression. This allows the `start-of-string` and `end-of-string` tokens to be included in the expression, and therefore gives you and exact match.

`^` is start-of-string and `$` is end-of-string.

```js
// cy.contains('[role=option', 'Numeric')  //matches two options

cy.contains('[role=option', /^Numeric$/) //matches one option only
```